# Creating a fractal tree in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, fractals

Having a little trouble creating a fractal in opengl. Here is my current code

```
void generateTree(){
  Point3f startPoint({0.0f,0.0f,0.0f});
  Point3f endPoint({1.0f,0.0f,0.0f});
  float rotation = 90.0f;
  glutWireSphere(0.05, 4, 4);
  _generateTreeBranches(startPoint,1.0f,rotation,0);
}

void _generateTreeBranches(const Point3f& newPosition,
                       float length,
                       float rotation,
                       const int depth)
{
  if(depth > MAX_DEPTH) return;
  cout << "at depth = " << depth << endl;


  if(depth == 0){
      glColor3f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
  }else if(depth == 1){
      glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
  }else{
      glColor3f(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
  }

  glTranslatef(newPosition.x,newPosition.y,newPosition.z);
  glRotatef(rotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  drawLine(length);
  glRotatef(-rotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
  glTranslatef(-newPosition.x,-newPosition.y,-newPosition.z);



  const float newLength = length * BRANCH_LENGTH_DECREASE_FACTOR;
  int nextDepth = depth + 1;
  Point3f nextPosition = {newPosition.x+length, newPosition.y, newPosition.z};

  float leftRotation = rotation + CHILD_BRANCH_ANGLE * nextDepth;
  _generateTreeBranches(nextPosition,newLength,leftRotation,nextDepth);

  float rightRotation = rotation - CHILD_BRANCH_ANGLE * nextDepth;
  _generateTreeBranches(nextPosition,newLength,rightRotation,nextDepth);

}
```

The positioning isn't correct, although the rotation seems to be right. The new branches arent' being draw starting at the end point of the parent's branch. Can someone help me on fixing this problem. Check out the full code [here](http://codepad.org/5M7fJJ0k)

Comment: I can see you are relying on stacking of glTranslatef and glRotatef functions through recursive calls to achieve your fractal tree. This is bad, because it is not always obvious what the final result would be and very easy to make mistakes. I would recommend that you perform the computation for rotation and translation of current branch mathematically and apply a single pair of glRotatef+glTranslatef once on each branch with glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix to reset it for next branch. Less confusion and more mathematically sound.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I was trying to avoid doing manual calculation, and just let opengl do the work, but for this case its probably better and easier to read if I do it out manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula for nextPosition is incorrect as it didn't factor in the direction which the current branch is facing

```
 Point3f nextPosition = {newPosition.x+length, newPosition.y, newPosition.z};
```

It should be something like this (please check exactly):

```
Point3f nextPosition = {newPosition.x+length*cos(rotation), newPosition.y+length*sin(rotation), newPosition.z};
```

Also, please use glLoadIdentity() to reset the matrix immediately like this:

```
glTranslatef(newPosition.x,newPosition.y,newPosition.z);
glRotatef(rotation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
drawLine(length);
glLoadIdentity();
```

It will be much clearer than what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, can you explain why I would use glLoadIdentity instead of offsetting the previous transformation? Also would I need to push/pop the matrix in the current stack?